# Android Wear device not detected when scanning Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os

I'm doing a bluetooth discovery (not Bluetooth LE) hoping to find my android wear but it is never found. The code for the discovery I'm pretty sure it's ok, because I can find other devices (TV's bluetooth, Sony smartband, etc) but never my Sony Smartwatch 3.

Any idea if this is even possible?

Here's the code:

```
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    context.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

...

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            if (!mDeviceList.contains(device)) {
                mDeviceList.add(device);
            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            // we're done here
            context.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
            final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            if (mOnBluetoothDiscoveryFinished != null) {
                mOnBluetoothDiscoveryFinished.onDiscoveryFinished(mDeviceList);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Cheers/

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out about this? I'm having a similar issue - Wear devices not appearing in BLE scans (using startLEScan where other BLE devices are found).

Comment: No solution unfortunately, I went for a workaround to scan bluetooth devices from wear. I kind of does the work for me

Comment: Same here, but that means no rssi (unless I'm missing something?), which is a bummer.